# Sublime Text 2, kemayo's git plugin, and Windows 7

Tags: git, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I'm going to preface with: I hope I can ask this question here, because it's not so much programming but using Sublime Text 2 and Git. I've scoured over the kemayo's instructions for hours, I must be missing something.

- The Problem: I do not understand how to integrate Git with Sublime Text 2 using kemayo's plugin.
- Problem 2: When doing ctrl+shift+p (command palette) I don't get any git commands.
- Additional info: I am new to Git, but I understand it enough to be able to use it using the standard command prompt.
- Method of kemayo installation: Package Manager
- OS: Windows 7 x64
- Git installed: Yes
- ***where git*** (Window's version of ***which git***): ***C:\git\cmd\git.cmd***
- I installed git to that path because it conatins no spaces or special characters. Of course, since **where git** works, this also means it's added to the enviro path.
- Git does work from the command prompt simply by just typing ***git***

*/Packages/User/Git.sublime-settings*

Things I've tried:

```
,"git_command": "'c:\\git\\bin\\git.exe'"
,"git_command": "c:/git/bin/git.exe"
,"git_command": "c:\\\\git\\\\bin\\\\git.exe"
,"git_command": "'c:\\git\\cmd\\git.cmd'"
,"git_command": "c:/git/cmd/git.cmd"
,"git_command": "c:\\\\git\\\\cmd\\\\git.cmd"
,"git_command": false
```

and more.

Things I also don't understand:

- kemayo's instructions for installation is still a little unclear. Is the only manual set up I have to do after installing via package manager is copy Git.sublime-settings over to the user folder? From my understanding, "git_command": false should work if git is in the path (which I'm quite sure it is). Optionally, you can manually set the path using that line, but I can't get it :(
- How do I configure it to use my BitBucket account? I've not come across any instructions on how to connect it to a remote repo

I tried to provide as much information regarding my problem as possible, but there are quite a few steps in setting up Git+ST2, so I could have forgotten to mention something. If I left something out, I will most certainly come back and add it.  Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one:

```
,"git_command": "c:/git/bin/git.exe"
```

is correct according to Win7 x64 format.

Make sure you have "C:\git\cmd" root in your $PATH environment variable. Try

```
echo %PATH%
```

in windows command line.

If you don't find that root in the response, you need to add "C:\git\cmd" to your $PATH variable. Java has a good manual on it: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 0):

1. Add **C:\git\cmd** to your $PATH environment variable
2. Open this >
   [image: Open this file]
3. **,"git_command": "c:/git/bin/git.exe"**

I Should Be Working

Press - ctrl+shift+p and type - git

Answer (score 0):

I have found that changing the Default settings does nothing. In the User settings, the following works for me:

```
,"git_command": "C:/cygwin/bin/git.exe"
```

I'm using the git installation from cygwin without any modifications and also without any path settings.

As an aside, thanks for the hints, everyone, I managed to set this up in about five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Github for Wundows](http://windows.github.com), your github.exe will not be in a convenient location. The path you need is something like this:

> C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_{somejunk}\bin\git.exe

I spent far too long trying to figure this out and none of the answers I found mentioned this, so hope this helps!